# How to make copyable Text Widget in Flutter?

Tags: clipboard, flutter

When long tab on [`Text` widget](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Text-class.html), a tooltip show up with 'copy'. When click on the 'copy' the text content should copy to system clipboard.

The following will copy the text on long tap, but does not show up 'copy', so user will not know, the content is copied to the clipboard.

```
class CopyableText extends StatelessWidget {
  final String data;
  final TextStyle style;
  final TextAlign textAlign;
  final TextDirection textDirection;
  final bool softWrap;
  final TextOverflow overflow;
  final double textScaleFactor;
  final int maxLines;
  CopyableText(
    this.data, {
    this.style,
    this.textAlign,
    this.textDirection,
    this.softWrap,
    this.overflow,
    this.textScaleFactor,
    this.maxLines,
  });
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new GestureDetector(
      child: new Text(data,
          style: style,
          textAlign: textAlign,
          textDirection: textDirection,
          softWrap: softWrap,
          overflow: overflow,
          textScaleFactor: textScaleFactor,
          maxLines: maxLines),
      onLongPress: () {
        Clipboard.setData(new ClipboardData(text: data));
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 159, accepted):

Since Flutter 1.9 you can use

```dart
SelectableText("Lorem ipsum...")
```

When text is selected the "Copy" context button will appear.

[image]

Answer (score 77):

You can use a [`SnackBar`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/SnackBar-class.html) to notify the user about the copy.

Here is a relevant code:

```
String _copy = "Copy Me";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final key = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
    return new Scaffold(
      key: key,
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Copy"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body:
      new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new GestureDetector(
              child: new Text(_copy),
              onLongPress: () {
                Clipboard.setData(new ClipboardData(text: _copy));
                key.currentState.showSnackBar(
                    new SnackBar(content: new Text("Copied to Clipboard"),));
              },
            ),
            new TextField(
                decoration: new InputDecoration(hintText: "Paste Here")),
          ]),


    );
  }
```

**EDIT**

I was working on something and I did the followin, so I thought of revisiting this answer:

[image]

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(home: new MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  String _copy = "Copy Me";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final key = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
    return new Scaffold(
      key: key,
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Copy"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body:
      new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new GestureDetector(
              child: new CustomToolTip(text: "My Copyable Text"),
              onTap: () {

              },
            ),
            new TextField(
                decoration: new InputDecoration(hintText: "Paste Here")),
          ]),


    );
  }
}

class CustomToolTip extends StatelessWidget {

  String text;

  CustomToolTip({this.text});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new GestureDetector(
      child: new Tooltip(preferBelow: false,
          message: "Copy", child: new Text(text)),
      onTap: () {
        Clipboard.setData(new ClipboardData(text: text));
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The answer is a widget, just wrap it in `class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget { ... }`

Comment: how to pass around Scaffold key, it will be inelegant for a small widget?

Comment: @CollinJackson yes, Wrap up to a `StatelessWidget` using  `final scaffold = Scaffold.of(context, nullOk: true);
        if (scaffold != null) {
          scaffold.showSnackBar(new SnackBar(content: new Text('Copied')));
        }`

Comment: how is clipboard defined?

Answer (score 17):

There is also list of properties it in SelectableText to enable option copy, paste, selectAll, cut

```
        child: Center(
            child: SelectableText('Hello Flutter Developer',
                cursorColor: Colors.red,
                showCursor: true,
                toolbarOptions: ToolbarOptions(
                copy: true,
                selectAll: true,
                cut: false,
                paste: false
                ),
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body2)
            ),
```

`SelectableText` widget

```
        const SelectableText(
            this.data, {
            Key key,
            this.focusNode,
            this.style,
            this.strutStyle,
            this.textAlign,
            this.textDirection,
            this.showCursor = false,
            this.autofocus = false,
            ToolbarOptions toolbarOptions,
            this.maxLines,
            this.cursorWidth = 2.0,
            this.cursorRadius,
            this.cursorColor,
            this.dragStartBehavior = DragStartBehavior.start,
            this.enableInteractiveSelection = true,
            this.onTap,
            this.scrollPhysics,
            this.textWidthBasis,
        })
```

[image]

Comment: Can you select part of text on ios? I found it can only select all on ios and can select part of text on android.

Comment: @David did you ever find a solution for this? I'm in a big bind because the app I created was entirely tested on Android / Linux, and now IOS doesn't allow text selection! Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

```
SelectableText(
  "Copy me",
  onTap: () {
    // you can show toast to the user, like "Copied"
  },
)
```

---

If you want to have different styling for text, use

```
SelectableText.rich(
  TextSpan(
    children: [
      TextSpan(text: "Copy me", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red)),
      TextSpan(text: " and leave me"),
    ],
  ),
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

I use Clipboard.setData inside function.

```dart
...
child: RaisedButton(
    onPressed: (){
        Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: "$textcopy"));
},
    disabledColor: Colors.blue[400],
    child: Text("Copy", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
),
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)?. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just use SelectableText

```
 SelectableText(
                iosInfo.identifierForVendor.toString(),
              ),
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a helper class **CopiableText** to accomplish my job. Just copy the class from below and put it in your code.

#### Helper class

`copiable_text_widget.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class CopiableText extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final String copyMessage;
  final Widget child;

  CopiableText(this.text, {this.copyMessage, this.child});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
            content: Text(this.copyMessage ?? 'Copied to clipboard'),
          ));
          Clipboard.setData(new ClipboardData(text: this.text));
        },
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 2),
            child: this.child ??
                Text(
                  this.text,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF1E272E), fontSize: 14),
                ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

#### Use it in different ways

```
import 'package:chaincargo_courier/ui/widgets/copiable_text_widget.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          // Just straightforward, click to copy
          CopiableText('You are awesome'),

          // Give a custom confirmation message
          CopiableText(
            'Asia, Nepal, Biratnagar',
            copyMessage: 'Address copied to clipboard',
          ),

          // Set custom child
          CopiableText(
            'Stunning view of mount everest',
            copyMessage: 'Caption copied to clipboard',
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Image.network(
                  'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2010/11/29/mount-everest-413_960_720.jpg',
                  errorBuilder: (BuildContext context, Object exception,
                      StackTrace stackTrace) {
                    return Text('Cannot load picture');
                  },
                ),
                Text('Stunning view of mount everest')
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Support Links and Copy&Paste

If you want to support both Links and Copy&Paste, use the [SelectableLinkify](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_linkify/latest/flutter_linkify/SelectableLinkify-class.html) widget.

This widget is part of the [flutter_linkify](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_linkify#selectable-text) package.

```
SelectableLinkify(
  text: "Made by https://cretezy.com\n\nMail: example@gmail.com",
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With Flutter version Flutter 3.3, you can now use [`SelectionArea`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SelectionArea-class.html).

It uses a platform-specific manner (using a Material toolbar on Android, and a Cupertino toolbar on iOS)!

[image]

```dart
SelectionArea(
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: const <Widget>[
                Text('Item 0', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50.0)),
                Text('Item 1', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50.0)),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
```

You can also customize the menu Toolbar using the [`contextMenuBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SelectionArea/contextMenuBuilder.html) property.