# Flutter How to handle text selection?

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I need to display a styled text for reading and some actions. User should be able **to select piece of text** and mark it with color, save it or expand it (show an additional information, for example a translation to another language).

I can display text by using RichText widget.

1) How to make it selectable and how/where to add onTextSelected listener? There is a class TextSelection but I can't see how/where its used.

2) What is a simplest way to expand text? I can reload full text (with changes added) and totally update widget, but this will result to scrolling to the top of a text and I think there should be a better approach.

Comment: Not a perfect solution but you can look into [this](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/rendering/RenderEditable-class.html) and [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/5422)

Comment: @Serge Breusov did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make copyable Text Widget in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46260055/how-to-make-copyable-text-widget-in-flutter)

Answer (score 12):

You now have `SelectableText()` widget available

Comment: Do note that a user can only select one SelectableText widget at a time.

Answer (score 1):

There is some progress in making text selection possible in Flutter. The only working solution at the moment is using `RenderEditable` with suppressed keyboard calls and removed cursor.

See [`flutter_selectable_text`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_selectable_text) plugin to make text selectable.

To also listen for selection events - consider using [`flutter_selectext`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_selectext) plugin, which also supports rich text (`TextSpan`).

---

However, I would recommend waiting for the official implementation that is [supposed to arrive](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/5422#issuecomment-490619617) in the end of May 2019.

Comment: The official release arrived -- but is currently borked for web.

Answer (score -2):

Use GestureDetector out of your text view. For example

```
GestureDetector(
          onTap: (){},
          child: Text(
            'Your text',
           style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),
          ),
        ),
```

And as for the rest of the question I dont understand

Comment: You completely misunderstood the question, I believe. The OP was asking about the `selectable` or `hightlightable` and 'expand` a `Text()` when `onClicked`