# How do I add copy action on a flutter textfield

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I'm trying to reproduce an application written in java on Android, using Flutter.

The thing I am stuck on is how to allow the user to copy from a read only TextField. Sadly I cannot find an answer in google.

In the old android app, the user inputs some criteria, the input is processed, and results output in a read only text field. If the user presses down on the read only text field, a copy/share context menu pops up, along with text anchors to mark the selection they want to copy. Standard stuff.

I have reproduced the rest of the application, up to the point of outputting the result in a read only TextField. But I just cannot work out how to implement the text anchor copy functionality.

I could really do with some pointers where to look for the solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46260055/how-to-make-copyable-text-flutter-widget

Comment: @Phix Yeah I've seen that answer but it doesn't replicate the <TextView android:textIsSelectable="true"> functionality, which has the effect of bringing up text anchors to set the region to be copied and the system popup menu to copy or share. Setting a TextField(enabled: false) would be the equivalent, except it makes the TextField non focusable, so you lose the ability to press on it in any capacity. It's looking more and more like this simple functionality is something Dart/Flutter simply can't do, which is very disappointing.

Comment: I see. Looks like there's discussion around it, i.e. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/5422#issuecomment-412289951

Comment: @Phix ooh, nice catch, I missed that. We decided to shelve Flutter for the moment as most of our inhouse apps take advantage of <TextView android:isTextSelectable>, but I've subscribed to that git thread to keep an eye on it. I am convinced Flutter is a tool we can leverage, it's just a shame that selectable TextField is a showstopper for us. We have a different POV from that of the maintainers, that raises the feature way above simply _nice to have_ lol

Answer (score 0):

While I don't think there's a way to do 100% exactly what you want (see [the link from the comment on the flutter issue for text not being selectable](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/5422#issuecomment-412289951)), there is a workaround that may do what you need.

What you could do instead of having them use the normal long press to select the text directly, is to have a button (or simply have them long press and automatically copy & show a toast/snackbar to tell them you have copied something) that copies the text.

You can then use flutter's [Clipboard](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/Clipboard-class.html) to set the data to the system clipboard.

There's also the [share plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/share) which may do what you want, but once again only for the entirety of the text rather than a part of it, unless you want to implement your own custom text selection...

Comment: Yeah I've looked at all the options and none of them do what is needed. Shame, but this was just an exercise to see if we could use Flutter for cross platform development. Having hit this snag, I went back and reviewed how much TextView copy is used by our apps/users and it was more than I expected. So we've decided to stay where we are. We don't have that many iOS devices in the company to warrant the effort. Hopefully we can revisit Flutter some time in the future because Flutter is definitely a good framework, I enjoyed working with it.

Comment: Fair enough, that's really too bad though. There seems to be quite a lot of things where flutter gets 90% of the way and the last 10% isn't important to the devs so it doesn't get done right away... but at the same time a good amount of things like that _have_ been fixed. So I wouldn't be surprised if this is fixed sooner rather than later. Give it a +1 (not a comment, a like) on the github thread and it'll raise it in their priority list - if they know people need things they're pretty good about fixing them when they get time.

Comment: BTW - did you check out https://github.com/CalebQ42/CustomDiceRoller/blob/master/lib/CustVars/Widgets/selectable_text.dart from the github comment thread? Mostly out of curiosity about what it does and how that differs from what you need.

Comment: Yeah I thumbed the thread and checked out the CalebQ42 post. It's on my list of things to look at when I get some time free after tomorrow, it's a holiday over here today, and there's only so much time the family let's me ignore them on my time of.