# How does flutter copy part of text in Text widget?

Tags: dart, flutter

[This solution is not too good](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46260055/how-to-make-copyable-text-flutter-widget)
It can only copy all, not the part. Does flutter have a ready-made solution? This requirement should be used very frequently. Is there a specific widget implementation?

Comment: You can copy any text you want `Clipboard.setData(new ClipboardData(text: text));` copies the text you pass. You can use TextEditingController to get the selected text https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes#2-use-a-texteditingcontroller