# Is it possible to use the platform's built-in cut/copy/paste menu?

Tags: flutter

Flutter's cut/copy/paste menu's buttons are affected by my app's button theme. And I also prefer to just use the platform's(Android's/iOS's) built-in cut/copy/paste menu.

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46260055/how-to-make-copyable-text-flutter-widget

Comment: @KhurshidAnsari that's still not the built-in popup.