# How to enable copy/paste on Flutter TextField widget?

Tags: flutter, clipboard

Trying to find the answer using Google search was a problem for me. This is really surprising. I want to be able to copy and paste TextField contents between different TextField's.

Comment: get your texfield value from textfieldcontroller and set value of other textfield

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

`SelectableText("hello over there")`

Answer (score 0):

use Clipboard

```
  Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: name_cont.text))
```

This answer may help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46260376/1136999